# Collapsable Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with two different custom table cells. The first cell appears normal after I start the app. The second cell will appear when you click on them.

Can anybody help me or has an idea?

Thanks a lot.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"customCell2";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"STHeitiSC-Light" size:9.0];
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: How can a cell appear after you click on it, if it hasn't yet appeared? What is the user tapping to make a cell appear?

Answer (score 1):

Having done custom UITableViewCell in the past I usually handle the nib loading in the custom class itself.

The basic header for the custom cell.

```
@interface RequestsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    // Ivars.
}
// Properties.
- (id) initWithRequestModel: (RequestModel *) model style:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier forQueryType:(int) requestType;
// Other methods, etc.
@end
```

The custom cell with a designated initializer.

```
@implementation RequestsTableViewCell

- (id) initWithRequestModel: (RequestModel *) model style:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier forQueryType:(int) requestType {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
       NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RequestsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        requestModel = model;
        queryType = requestType;
        [self setRequestThumbnail];
        [self setRequestCategory];
        [self setRequestAddress];
        [self setRequestStatusDate];
        [self setRequestStatus];
        [self setRequestFollowed];
        [self setRequestComment];
        [self setAppearance];
    }

    return self;
}
```

There would also be a custom xib for the custom UITableViewCell that corresponds and has the custom class set in the identity inspector.

In the UITableViewController.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"Cell Id";
    RequestModel *request = nil;

    // Other code for search, etc

    request = [self.serviceRequests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    RequestsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];

    if(!cell) {
        cell = [[RequestsTableViewCell alloc] initWithRequestModel:request style:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId forQueryType:queryTypeIndicator];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

It also sounds like you have more than one custom cell type in your question? Can you elaborate on how it is all supposed to function? You say that you have to click one cell to make another appear, can you explain that interaction?

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar, but made the cell 'expand', instead of adding a new cell. Of course then you don't have two cells, but you can resize your one cell, add subframes,...

You can keep a boolean in your UITableViewCell object (`BOOL cellIsExpanded`), and set that on tap gesture. Then in drawRect of the TableViewCell, layout your cell accordingly.

Example code, on expand, make cell height 20-->80 and add a UIButton:

In the TableViewController, overload heightForRowAtIndexPath (this will resize your cell if 'expanded'):

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourEntity *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!record.cellIsExpanded)
        return 20.; // cell is smaller if collapsed
    else
        return 80.; // bigger cell
}
```

In the TableViewCell, add or remove subframes:

```
@interface MyTableViewCell ()
@property(nonatomic) BOOL cellIsExpanded
@property(strong, nonatomic) UITextField *myTextField;
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIButton *clickMeButton;
@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(!self.cellIsExpanded){
        // layout your collapsed cell, for example:
        self.myTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        self.myTextField.text = @"Collapsed cell";
        // remove button, only present in expanded view :
        self.clickMeButton=nil;
    }
    else{
        self.myTextField.text = @"Expanded cell";
        // add button below textfield
        self.clickMeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 10, 10)];
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you all for the solutions. My solution is, i expand the tablecell :)

Comment: But now I have another problem. The contents of the cell is now overlapped on the other cell.

how do you solve the problem? the content is drawn later?

Comment: Is your cell heigh enough? Do you use the heightForRowAtIndexPath? Can't you increase the height for the expanded cell?

Comment: what this code do ? YourEntity *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: It gets the object from the fetchedResultsController at indexPath. That object will typically be your own entity, the object you get from your database (if you show a list of contacts in your tableview, that would be `Contact*`). I assumed you don't have a static table view.

Comment: My app parse a website and then you can see a overview of this data in this cells. The tablecell is a customcell with .h, .m and a xib. When the user click on this cell i want expand this one cell so that the user see more information on this cell. I dont know how I can put the content in this expand table cell.